# Does the API support viewing user's voting activity?

Tags: support, api

For research purposes, I need to view users' voting behavior.
I didn't see this option in the api documentation: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs 
On the other hand, When viewing a user's page, I can see their voting behavior under the vote tab.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

No. Votes are anonymous. Hence, you can't find them in the site, data dump or API. You can only view your votes on the site, not others.

Only the total number of votes is public. Those can be accessed via all above mentioned resources.

Answer (score 1):

The [users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) method of the API can return the number of upvotes and downvotes for each user.

However, for downloading a massive amount of information about users I recommend working with the Users table of SE data dump, available via [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Mr L. cohen :). I study the temporal behavior and the user API only gives me the total number. Is it possible to get all voting records of a user via the data explorer?

Comment: No, individual votes are private information, only the totals are disclosed.