# Is it possible using the SE API to get a list of another user's posts that I have upvoted?

Tags: support, up-votes, api

I'm looking to obtain a list of another user's posts that I have upvoted.  I learned in [a previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288239/232449) that this is not possible through the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, because any private data, including up/down votes, are not included in the SEDE data dumps.

That left me wondering: Is such a list theoretically possible to obtain by writing my own app that uses the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)?  If so, are there any apps that anyone has written that already do this?

---

I have seen this question: [Does the API support viewing user's voting activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250644/does-the-api-support-viewing-users-voting-activity) However, that question appears to be asking if it is possible to view all users votes, as the OP wants to do some sort of study on different users' voting activity.  I realize that it would not be possible to see *any* users votes, as that is private information.  What I'm asking, however, is whether it would be possible to write an app using the API that would allow me to *log in and view my own votes*.  This would be similar to what is available on the website looking at my own profile, but because I'm writing my own app, I could potentially do more searching and present the data in a different way than what is available on my profile tab.  The answers on that other question do not explicitly answer this question.

Comment: @ale: That's talking about *users in general*, as opposed to *this authenticated user*, but unfortunately, as answered [on StackApps](//stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users), it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Since you are just trying to focus on one user, this is doable.  Otherwise see [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278090/can-i-see-who-i-voted-for), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175722/148310). (And upvote the last, at least.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the API support viewing user's voting activity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250644/does-the-api-support-viewing-users-voting-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  You can do this with the API, but it's a bit of work.
Here's the approach:

1. Get [an `access_token` with the `private_info` scope](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).
2. Query a list of your target user's posts using [the /users/{ids}/posts route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-users), BUT:

   1. You will have to pass the access token.
   2. You will need to use a filter that returns [the `upvoted` property](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post).
3. Page through the post results as needed and check the `upvoted` property for each post entry.
   This gives you the list you are looking for.